# Getting Error: Unable to resolve module `./YellowBoxImageSource` from react-native metro server

Tags: react-native

Just trying to put icons in the bottom tab navigation. Using react-native cli 0.6x without expo. Can anyone help me to fix it? I have put a screenshot of this error here in the link.
[error snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZO1yi.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```sh
react-native start --reset-cache
```

I've seen this on gitHub

Comment: It would have been nice if you remembered and added the link :)